# Simple Boolean "Latch" with state

Tags: c++, c++17

Sometimes you need to do things when a condition changes, here is a simple class to keep track of the state of the last call and execute callbacks when the state changes.

```
#include <functional>
#include <cassert>


/// latch is a class that contains of a test function and a couple of callbacks, when the return
/// value of the test function changes the approrpiate callback gets called, as long as the return
/// value of the test function stays the same no callbacks will be called. Callbacks may be nullptr
template<class...Args>
class Latch {
public:
    Latch(std::function<bool(Args ...)> shouldLatch, std::function<void(Args...)> onLatch = nullptr, std::function<void(Args...)> onUnlatch = nullptr) :
                m_shouldLatch(std::move(shouldLatch)),
                m_onLatch(std::move(onLatch)),
                m_onUnlatch(std::move(onUnlatch)) {}

    bool latched() const noexcept { return m_isLatched; }
    
    explicit operator bool() const noexcept { return m_isLatched; }

    void update(Args&& ... args)
    {
        if (m_shouldLatch && m_isLatched != m_shouldLatch(std::forward<Args>(args)... ))
        {
            m_isLatched = !m_isLatched;
            auto& call = (m_isLatched) ?  m_onLatch : m_onUnlatch;
            if (call) call(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
    }


private:
    bool m_isLatched = false;
    std::function<bool(Args ...)> m_shouldLatch;
    std::function<void(Args ...)> m_onLatch;
    std::function<void(Args ...)> m_onUnlatch;
};

int main() 
{
    int onLatch = 0;
    int onUnlatch = 0;
    int latchVal = 1;


    Latch<int> l1([&latchVal](auto val){return val == latchVal;},
                  [&onLatch](auto val){++onLatch;},
                  [&onUnlatch](auto val){++onUnlatch;});
    assert(!l1);
    l1.update(0);
    assert(!l1);
    assert(onLatch == 0 && onUnlatch == 0);
    l1.update(1);
    assert(l1.latched());   
    assert(onLatch == 1 && onUnlatch == 0);
    l1.update(1);
    assert(onLatch == 1 && onUnlatch == 0);
    l1.update(0);
    assert(onLatch == 1 && onUnlatch == 1);

    Latch l2 = l1;
}
```

This is also at https://www.godbolt.org/z/z4b934

Thanks for the input

Comment: What are you looking to improve?

Comment: Wasn’t looking for any specifics, just a general review. checking the use of variable template arguments and forwarding for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not much to improve in my opinion, except:

## Unnecessary use of `std::move()`

You are passing `shouldLatch`, `onLatch` and `onUnlatch` by value to the constructor, so there is no reason to use `std::move()` in the member initializer list.